# mysql - strange result with IN-function with id list in quotes

Tags: mysql

When i run this code it returns me as expected all sites with the listed ids

```
SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE id IN (142,150,40,42,21,99,162,110,121)
```

But this returns only the site with the id 142. Why does this even return something? I would have expected an error.

```
SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE id IN ("142,150,40,42,21,99,162,110,121")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql (correctly) doesn't look inside the string to see that it contains something that looks like an in list.

It just sees an `in` list with a single item that is a string. You get an implicit cast from `string` to `int` to convert that single expression.

But instead of doing the sensible thing and raising an error because the string `"142,150,40,42,21,99,162,110,121"` is not remotely a valid integer it stops at the first non numeric character and so the string casts to `142`.

So your query is evaluated as `in (142)`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select 1 + "142,150,40,42,21,99,162,110,121";
+---------------------------------------+
| 1 + "142,150,40,42,21,99,162,110,121" |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                   143 |
+---------------------------------------+
```

In [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert), it states that:

- *To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, you normally do not have to do anything other than to use the string value as though it were a number*
- *If you use a string in an arithmetic operation, it is converted to a floating-point number during expression evaluation.*

Your string is *numified*